# object set_origin not working

Tags: python, objects, operator

I have been looking at similar questions yet the following script is not returning any error but the origin of the object is not changed. What did I not set right? The context seems ok since I have selected and activated the object first:

```
imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = the_file_path)
bpy.data.objects['Blob'].select = True

the_object = [ o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.select ][0]
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = the_object

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
```

there is only one active and selected object which is 'Blob'. Here is a picture of the result:

Here is a link with the imported file : https://gist.github.com/compmonks/dd997dc53bb0dcd48de2fe077866266f

**EDIT**

This script is loaded with Blender on the command line so there is no direct access to context areas and so on. This causes some operators to not function properly. I found that loading blender with a blend file and the script was avoiding this problem. Not sure if this is the correct way to do so :

```
import os
os.system("THE_BLENDER_PATH THE_BLENDER_FILE.blend --python THE_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But even if another object was selected, no object is having its origin set to the geometry. The current context mode is OBJECT but I am wondering if this needs some kind of override

Comment: I edited the question with a picture. There is only the one mesh object returned as active and selected

Comment: just added a link in the question. The blender scene in which it is imported already contains objects. That's why I am making sure it is the only one selected and active first

Comment: the obj file is right below but you can also get it through: https://gist.github.com/compmonks/dd997dc53bb0dcd48de2fe077866266f#file-blob-obj